# Prove an inequality involving a norm

Tags: calculus, functions, inequality, normed-spaces, inner-products

We define the following inner product on intergrable, $2\pi$ periodic functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{C}$:

$$\langle f,g\rangle = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t)\overline{g(t)}\ dt$$

I need to prove that:

$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \left|f(t)\right| dt \le \sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{\int_{-\pi}^\pi \left|f(t)\right|^2\ dt} = 2\pi \|f\|$$

Now, Cauchy-Schwarz inequality seemed to me perfect for this:

$$2\pi\|f\| =\|2\pi\|\|f\| \ge |\langle f, 2\pi \rangle| = \left| \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t)\ dt\right|$$

but of course, we need the absolute value for the integrand.

I've also tried to use the fact that $f$ is bounded but that didn't yield anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are almost done, just note that 
$$ \def\norm#1{\left\|#1\right\|}\def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}\norm{\abs f} = \norm{f}, $$
now start your calculations with 
$$ 2\pi\norm f = \cdots = \abs{\left<\abs f, 2\pi\right>}  =  \int_{-\pi}^\pi \abs{f(t)}\, dt $$
and you are done.

Comment: great, thank you martini!